# Change array keys to numeric in PHPExcel

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

Hi guys i am working on PHPExcel to read a xls file. i am using this line to get data from xls in array

```
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

Its working fine but giving me array is like this

```
    Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => category_id (*)
            [B] => category_name (*)
            [C] => name_en (*)
        )
)
```

As you can see its puting keys as alphabets not numbers

```
        [A] => category_id (*)
        [B] => category_name (*)
        [C] => name_en (*)
```

but i want my array like this having numeric keys not alphabets like

```
    Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => category_id (*)
            [1] => category_name (*)
            [2] => name_en (*)
        )
)
```

There is a way to convert this array to numberic keys

> `$type = array_values(array_map('array_values', $sheetData));`

but how can i fetch data like this array using PHPExcel i have search a lot but didn't find any solution.

Comment: just `$arr[1] = array_values($arr[1])` makes indexes numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the last argument to false to get numeric index

```
->toArray(null,true,true,false);
```

Comment: thanks for your help working perfectly fine...
 its an off topic question but can you please tell me how to count all rows in all sheets of xls file using PHPExcel ..?

Comment: In answer to your new question: `listWorksheetInfo()` [PHPExcel Docs](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/07-Helper-Methods.md), we do try to provide documentation for a reason

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
$input_file_type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($path_to_file);
$obj_reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($input_file_type);
$obj_php_excel = $obj_reader->load($path_to_file);

//  Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $obj_php_excel->getSheet(0); 
$highest_row = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highest_column = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highest_row; $row++){
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $row_data = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highest_column . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
    $excel_data[] = $row_data[0];
}
```